# How to Test the unit test file angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

This may seems silly to you, but I am worried from last couple of days, because I am new to angularjs and jasmine as well

Here I have downloaded the angular-seed-master from https://github.com/angular/angular-seed
 and the Directory structure is :

[image]

In my app/js folder I have a file called controllers.js having the code

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).controller('MyCtrl1', ["$scope",function($scope) {

    $scope.name = 'Hello World!'; 

  }]);
```

And created the file called `home.tests.js` in the same folder and has the code like

```
'use strict';

describe('MyCtrl1', function () {
            var scope, $httpBackend; //we'll use these in our tests

            //mock Application to allow us to inject our own dependencies
            beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));
            //mock the controller for the same reason and include $rootScope and $controller
            beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($rootScope) {
                    //create an empty scope
                    scope = $rootScope.$new();
                    //declare the controller and inject our empty scope
                    $controller('MyCtrl1', {
                        $scope: scope
                    });
                }));
                // tests start here
                it('should have variable text = "Hello World!"', function () {
                    expect(scope.text).toBe('Hello World!');
                });
            });
```

And my karma file is like:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Tue Jul 15 2014 14:30:06 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
    'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
    'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'app/js/*.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

And have included the file in index.html :

My index.html file :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#/view1">view1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/view2">view2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div ng-view></div>

  <div>Angular seed app: v<span app-version></span></div>

  <!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <link data-require="jasmine" data-semver="2.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/2.0.0/jasmine.css" />
    <script data-require="json2" data-semver="0.0.2012100-8" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20121008/json2.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jasmine" data-semver="2.0.0" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/2.0.0/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jasmine" data-semver="2.0.0" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/2.0.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jasmine@*" data-semver="2.0.0" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/2.0.0/boot.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js" data-semver="1.2.16" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-mocks" data-semver="1.2.16" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular-mocks.js"></script>    

  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script> <!--Controller file-->
  <script src="js/home.tests.js"></script> <!--Testing file-->
</body>
</html>
```

So when I run the file as with my domain as `http://local.collective.net/#/view1`

Error looks like: 
[image]

Please let me know, what is the problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors:

What `angular.mock.module` (or `module` which is an alias) does is to load a module into the test.

You're trying to load `myApp` module to test a controller that is NOT in that module but `myApp.controllers`. The dot on there is not making any type of relation or inheritance, it is just a name, so if you have the controller on that exact module, you need to load it.

On the other hand, on the test, you are using `$controller` but you haven't injected it and also you're expecting a `scope.text` when you want to say `scope.name`.

See it working [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/LVPkRArgPbnKozQWhbtR?p=preview)